# TCP TIME_WAIT Assassination

Tags: tcp

**I just looked up the [RFC1337](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1337) about TIME_WAIT Assassination and this is a portion of it.**

> Figure 1 shows an example of TIME-WAIT assassination.  Segments 1-5
> are copied exactly from Figure 13 of RFC-793, showing a normal close
> handshake.  Packets 5.1, 5.2, and 5.3 are an extension to this
> sequence, illustrating TWA.   Here 5.1 is *any* old segment that is
> unacceptable to TCP A.  It might be unacceptable because of its
> sequence number or because of an old PAWS timestamp.  In either case,
> TCP A sends an ACK segment 5.2 for its current SND.NXT and RCV.NXT.
> Since it has no state for this connection, TCP B reflects this as RST
> segment 5.3, which assassinates the TIME-WAIT state at A!
>
> **
>
> ```
>     RFC 1337                 TCP TIME-WAIT Hazards                  May 1992
>            TCP A                                                TCP B
>        1.  ESTABLISHED                                          ESTABLISHED
>            (Close)
>        2.  FIN-WAIT-1  --> <SEQ=100><ACK=300><CTL=FIN,ACK>  --> CLOSE-WAIT
>        3.  FIN-WAIT-2  <-- <SEQ=300><ACK=101><CTL=ACK>      <-- CLOSE-WAIT
>                                                                 (Close)
>        4.  TIME-WAIT   <-- <SEQ=300><ACK=101><CTL=FIN,ACK>  <-- LAST-ACK
>        5.  TIME-WAIT   --> <SEQ=101><ACK=301><CTL=ACK>      --> CLOSED
>       - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
>        5.1. TIME-WAIT   <--  <SEQ=255><ACK=33> ... old duplicate
>        5.2  TIME-WAIT   --> <SEQ=101><ACK=301><CTL=ACK>    -->  ????
>        5.3  CLOSED      <-- <SEQ=301><CTL=RST>             <--  ????
>           (prematurely)
>
> **
> ```

**Now, what confuses me is, in TCP/IP Illustrated volume1, what it says is:**

> Any delayed segments that arrive for a connection while it is in the
> 2MSL wait are discarded.

**So, why did the TCP A in RFC 1337's figure 1 ACK the old duplicate segment?**

Comment: By Delayed Segments do they imply application payload data, not tcp control data?   Is it not “ACK ing” the TIME-WAIT state telling you what the status of that connection is ?

Comment: @SqlSurfer RFC: "Here 5.1 is any old segment that is unacceptable to TCP A", seems he didn't specify a segment type.

Comment: And I can't figure out what exactly does "Is it not “ACK ing” the TIME-WAIT state telling you what the status of that connection is ?" means since I got poor English skill....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RFC 793 states in 'Reset generation':

> 3. If the connection is in a synchronized state (ESTABLISHED,
>      FIN-WAIT-1, FIN-WAIT-2, CLOSE-WAIT, CLOSING, LAST-ACK, TIME-WAIT),
>      any unacceptable segment (out of window sequence number or
>      unacceptible acknowledgment number) must elicit only an empty
>      acknowledgment segment containing the current send-sequence number
>      and an acknowledgment indicating the next sequence number expected
>      to be received, and the connection remains in the same state.

Comment: Is that means it's actually not ACKing the segment, just have to send an ack because of the discarded of the wrong(unacceptable) segment ?

Comment: The ACK does give you a new sequence number so that you can send a message that will not be out of sequence if you are trying to do some  specialized control work.. (Right?)  What scares me about this discussion is that you get into the implementation details of the stack and then you wonder why your app does not work on a future 1.21 Gigawatt network card that will come out.  This is where firewalls and virtual hardware starts to get nervous.

Comment: @Kevin That is correct, it is readvertising its current sequence number and window.

Comment: @SqlSurfer I don't know what the part of your comment after 'what scares me' has to do with my answer, or indeed what it means.

Comment: @EJP That confuses me more than my original question xD.